# Multiple hasMany associations within one model

Tags: json, sencha-touch-2, associations, has-many

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
                orderId : '00410',
                name : 'Zuiger',
                productionQuantity : '4',
                materials : [
                    {
                      materialId    : 'ALU.BALK.10X70',
                      description   : 'Aluminium balk 10 x 70',
                      quantityPP    : '70mm',
                      totalQuantity : '0.4'
                    },
                    {
                      materialId    : 'ALU.BALK.10X70',
                      description   : 'Aluminium balk 10 x 70',
                      quantityPP    : '70mm',
                      totalQuantity : '0.4'
                    }],
                operations : [
                    {
                      operationId   : 'ZAGEN',
                      lineNr        : '10',
                      description   : 'Zagen groot',
                      started   : false
                    }, 
                    {
                      operationId   : 'FR003',
                      lineNr        : '20',
                      description   : 'Frezen Heidenhein',
                      started   : true
                    }] 
            }
```

So i have an Order, which has a list of materials and/or a list of operations. This JSON is currently in a Store file using the Data tag and is autoLoaded. This is for testing purposes.

The model used for this is Order which contains 2 hasMany associations to material and operation:

```
Ext.define('wp-touch.model.Order', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

requires: [ 
           'wp-touch.model.Material', 
           'wp-touch.model.Operation'
           ],

config: {
    idProperty: 'Id',       
    fields: [
            { name: 'orderId',  type: 'string'},
            { name: 'name',     type: 'string'},        
            { name: 'productionQuantity', type: 'string'},
    ],
    associations: [
              { 
                type: 'hasMany',
                associationKey: 'materials',
                model: 'wp-touch.model.Material',
                name: 'material',
                primairyKey: 'materialId',
                foreignKey: 'orderId'
              },
              { 
                type: 'hasMany',
                associationKey: 'operations',
                model: 'wp-touch.model.Operation', 
                name: 'operation',
                primairyKey: 'operationId',
                foreignKey: 'orderId'
              }   
    ],

}});
```

When the store is loaded it only loads the first hasMany. When i empty the materials array in the JSON message it loads in the operations just fine. So it seems it only loads one of the hasMany associations. Is there any way to fix this?

Here are the material and operation models;

```
Ext.define('wp-touch.model.Material', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    idProperty: 'Id',

    fields: [
            { name: 'materialId',   type: 'string'},
            { name: 'description',  type: 'string'},
            { name: 'quantityPP',   type: 'string'},
            { name: 'totalQuantity',type: 'string'},
            { name: 'orderId',      type: 'string'}
    ],
    belongsTo: [
                { 
                    model: 'wp-touch.model.Order',
                    name: 'order',
                    primairyKey: 'materialId',
                    foreignKey: 'orderId' 
                }
    ]
}});

Ext.define('wp-touch.model.Operation', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    idProperty: 'Id',

    fields: [
            { name: 'operationId',  type: 'string'},
            { name: 'lineNr',       type: 'int'},       
            { name: 'description',  type: 'string'},
            { name: 'started',      type: 'boolean'},
            { name: 'orderId',      type: 'string'}
    ],
    belongsTo: [
                { 
                    model: 'wp-touch.model.Order', 
                    name: 'order',
                    primairyKey: 'operationId',
                    foreignKey: 'orderId' 
                }
    ]
}});
```

Comment: You're spelling `primaryKey` incorrectly.

Comment: You're right, i fixed this but this didn't seem to be issue.